# Update record if somcolumn!="somevalue", using Hibernate saveorupdate()

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to write Criteria in Hibernate, My desired output is if column empfield1's value is not 'REGULARIZE' then update else do not update record.

i have tried below one.

```
Session session = factory1.openSession();
    Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(EmployeePunch.class);
            criteria.add(Restrictions.ne("empField1","REGULARIZE"));
EmployeePunch empPunch = (EmployeePunch)criteria.uniqueResult();
            empPunch.setId(empPuncId);
            empPunch.setSigninTime(inTime);
            empPunch.setSigninDate(dateOfUpdate);
            empPunch.setSignoutTime(outTime);
            empPunch.setPresent(presentStatus);
            empPunch.setLastUpdateBy(empcode);
            empPunch.setLastUpdateDate(time);   
            empPunch.setEmpField1(remark);  
            session.saveOrUpdate(empPunch);
            tx.commit();
```

but it gives me error

```
Exception : query did not return a unique result: 527
```

Comment: That's a clear exception. Which part of it don't you understand?

Comment: Why do you do setId(empPuncId)? Is this a primary key for an existing record? Or where does empPuncId come from?

Comment: actually i am beginner to hibernate. initially i didn't understand the meaning of exception but now i understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forget to give id without giving id hibernate will return multiple records with `empField1="REGULARIZE"`

You should give id as well like below:

```
Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(EmployeePunch.class);
         criteria.add(Restrictions.ne("empField1","REGULARIZE"))
         .add(Restrictions.eq("empPuncId",empPuncId));
```

Now it will return single matching record and then update it.

Comment: I got the problem but, it was not able to update the record finally i took result into list then compared the list size if list is not empty then saveOrUpdate else do nothing.

Comment: Yes if you not have any record with specified id you need to do the same

Answer (score 1):

That means ,With that `criteria` there are multiple records are there in your `Database`.

To know how many records are there,

Try

```
List<EmployeePunch> emps = (ArrayList<EmployeePunch>)criteria.list();
```

So that `emps`  will give you a list of  `EmployeePunch's` which meets the criteria.

Then iterate the list and see how many items are there inside database.

Comment: yes. I missed to mention id in critera. i took result into list and comapred the list size if list is not empty then update otherwise do nothing.

Comment: @user1363086  Now you resolved the issue ??Now what you can do is.Simply get result and get the first element like `resultlist.get(0)`,and then update it.That will give you first element of the list,regardless of uniqueness and don't forget to add a null check for the returned `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a HQL in this way?

```
Query query = session.createQuery("update EmployeePunch set signinTime = :signinTime, signinDate = :signinDate where empField1 = 'REGULARIZE').setParameter("signinTime",signinTime).setParameter("signinDate",signinDate);
int updateRecordCount = query.executeUpdate();
```

Of course, you have to set values for other properties (except for Id if it is your @Id field); in `updateRecordCount` you get the count of updated records.